# atributo mailto não abre

Tags: javascript, html, email

Estou usando a tag html para link de email:

```
<a href ="mailto:xpto@internet.com">Entre em contato</a>
```

Mas simplesmente não abre, nada ocorre. 
Meu SO é Windows 7 ultimate 32bits
Servidor de email é thunderbird e já testei no opera, chrome e explorer e nenhum funciona.

Testei outras tags de link url e funciona normalmente

Comment: Aqui funcionou no Chrome Win10 sem problemas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom, em primeiro lugar, não há nada de errado com seu código e ele pode ser testado abaixo:
O que eu adicionei e pode te ajudar é um "hack" para verificar o evento "window blur" assim que disparado o evento

```js
(function($) {
  $('a[href^=mailto]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).click(function() {
      var t;
      var self = $(this);

      $(window).blur(function() {
        // The browser apparently responded, so stop the timeout.
        clearTimeout(t);
      });

      t = setTimeout(function() {
        // The browser did not respond after 500ms, so open an alternative URL.
        document.location.href = '...';
      }, 500);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href ="mailto:xpto@internet.com">Entre em contato</a>
```

Referências
https://www.uncinc.nl/nl/articles/dealing-mailto-links-if-no-mail-client-available
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214686/detecting-when-mailto-failed

Comment: Amigo atualizei o explorer e executei o codigo e ja me mostrou que é um problema no servidor de email. Não sei o que houve, pois tava funcionando. Mas valeu pelo direcionamento!